# How does one say “cream of the crop” in French?

Tags: anglais, expressions

Would it be “*crème de la crème*” (which might be a close French equivalent)? Or is there a separate expression?

Someone was asking a question on the English language site, what is meant by “[cream of the crop?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41325/cream-of-the-crop)”
But not “necessarily” about the French version, although they speculated the origin might be French.

Comment: You could also use "Le Top", although it's a much more recent expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La [crème](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_%28produit_laitier%29) est la partie du lait qui concentre le plus de graisse, et elle flotte sur le reste. Le mot *[crème](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cr%C3%A8me)* peut désigner métaphoriquement un des meilleurs éléments d'un ensemble, en général dans une expression de la forme *la crème de [quelque chose]*. On retrouve ce sens dans [beaucoup de langues européennes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cream#Translations). Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait là un lien étymologique, mais plutôt des référents culturels partagées (place du lait dans l'alimentation, valorisation de la graisse, valorisation de ce qui est au-dessus).

*La crème de la crème* n'est pas vraiment une expression consacrée en français, même si elle se rencontre quelquefois. On indique en général dans quel ensemble l'objet considéré est un des meilleurs : « la crème des hommes », « la crème de l'esthétique », ... Le [*Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/cr%C3%A8me) indique le sens valorisant dès sa première édition ; l'utilisation valorisante sans complément explicite me semble vieillie. Plus fréquemment que *crème de la crème*, on parle quelquefois du *[fin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fin/adjectif) du fin* (qui désigne plutôt la clé d'un mystère, mais on le trouve aussi dans le sens de la meilleure partie). On peut aussi utiliser le nom [summum](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/summum) pour désigner un extrême, mais cela n'a pas de valeur laudative (on peut parler du *summum de la bêtise* aussi bien que du *summum de l'intelligence*).

On utilise des fois d'autres mots que la crème pour désigner le meilleur de quelque chose. Lorsqu'il s'agit d'une période temporelle, on parle souvent de la *[fleur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fleur)* (« la fleur de la jeunesse » : la période la plus agréable de la jeunesse). On peut aussi parler du *[fleuron](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fleuron)* pour désigner la chose la plus importante (« le fleuron de la jeunesse » : les jeunes les plus importants, la future élite d'une nation). Pour parler des couches sociales huppées, on parle familièrement du *[gratin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gratin)*.

[de la crème,crème de la,crème de la crème,fin du fin,summum http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=de%20la%20cr%C3%A8me%2Ccr%C3%A8me%20de%20la%2Ccr%C3%A8me%20de%20la%20cr%C3%A8me%2Cfin%20du%20fin%2Csummum&corpus=7&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=de+la+cr%C3%A8me%2Ccr%C3%A8me+de+la%2Ccr%C3%A8me+de+la+cr%C3%A8me%2Cfin+du+fin%2Csummum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de ce qui te fais dire que "crème de la crème" n'est pas vraiment consacrée en français...? C'est de loin la première expression que je vois/entends utilisée dans ce genre de cas. Bien entendu, elle est moins répandue que des mots tels que "summum", mais reste assez fréquente pour une locution figée.

Comment: Je n'avais jamais entendu _fin du fin_ pour parler d'un mystère. Sinon, il y a aussi _le nec plus ultra_ (listé comme synonyme de _fin du fin_) et le mélange _la fine fleur_.

Comment: @Joubarc Pour *la fine fleur* ce n'est pas à la fleur de sel qu'on fait allusion ?

Comment: @Evpok Plutôt la farine, en fait. (Voir [fleur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fleur) et chercher _fine_ plusieurs fois. En tous cas ça a aussi pris la signification de « ce qui est à la surface de quelque chose; ce qui est supérieur à quelque chose. » (première occurence de _fine_ dans le lien).

Comment: ...et pour compliquer le tout : farine en anglais ? *flour*

Answer (score 7):

Gilles a répondu sur la crème, il reste la structure.  Quand on pense à *bon entre les bons*, *juste entre les justes*, ... ça ressemble à la manière habituelle de rendre les superlatifs dans certaines traductions de la Bible (l'hébreu n'a pas de superlatif et utilise des constructions similaires).

Ça rappelle aussi le titre de *roi des rois* portés au moins par les souverains de Perse et d'Abyssinie.

Comment: Aussi l'_as des as_, le _crac des cracs_,…

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the closest expression in french is [`fin du fin`](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fin_du_fin). It means:

> Ce qu’il y a de mieux dans le genre, ce qui ce fait de mieux.

Answer (score 3):

Cette expression désigne l'élite ! C'est bien la même qu'en anglais.

Answer (score 1):

One additional way to express it, albeit essentially in the negative way, would be ['La fleur des pois'](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fleur_des_pois)

> C'est pas la fleur des pois !

meaning he is NOT the cream of the crop.
This expression is used nearly only for a person or a group of person, not an object. It can sometime be used for an ideology or some similarly abstracts things.